The Petersen Graph (Exercise 1.1.19 in West's GT)
The exercise states the following

1.1.19. The Petersen graph. Prove that the graphs drawn in Example 1.1.19 are pairwise isomorphic. (Comment: one can use disjoint vertex sets and establish the required bijections or give all the graphs the same vertex set, assigned so that the graphs have the same adjacency matrix).

Here are the graphs drawn in 1.1.19

After some playing around with the Petersen graph I was able to draw the following

Drawing 1
Drew the Petersen graph and partitioned the vertex set into two subsets (reds and blues). Then wondered what the induced subgraph under these two subsets are.
Drawing 2
Taking the induced subgraph of both the red and blue vertex subsets induces two disjoint 5-vertex cycles.
Drawing 3
Now, take into account all edges missing from drawing 2 which if added match the original graph in drawing 1. These edges in drawing 3 are part of a bipartite graph where all vertices in one coloring are in an independent set.
Conclusion and Question
Then if what we are trying to show is that the graphs drawn in 1.1.19 are pairwise isomorphic it would be equivalent to decomposing each graph as shown in drawing 2 and drawing 3. To my knowledge, the isomorphism class for drawing 2 is all graphs $G$ such that $G \cong C_5+C_5$, and for drawing 3 is all graphs $G$ such that $G$ is one-regular and $G\cong K_{5,5}$.
But is this right? I want to connect these ideas to then follow the heuristic mentioned in the quote.

Is being able to partition two graphs' vertex sets so that their drawings 2 and 3 are equivalent enough to establish an isomorphism? It very well may be, but actually justifying that may be more laborious than just doing the problem the way it says to do it in the quote. Do you understand that way it is telling you to do it?

True, it would be almost like sketching a proof in the direction I am headed. But, yes I would like to understand a systematic approach to determine if any given graph is pairwise isomorphic to the Petersen graph. Even ones that aren't in example 1.1.19 from the book

The point of the exercise is to understand what it means for graphs to be isomorphic, and to understand that a given graph can have many different-seeming depictions. The exercise is to be done by just labelling the vertices 1-10 in the appropriate manner. The question of the best ways to determine if an arbitrary graph is isomorphic to the Peterson graph is a more general question than what the problem is asking, and it is not explicitly stated in your post.
